# Is it possible to build a small web site with vanilla Mathematica? How about a web server?

Tags: web-access, html, webservices, web, css

*Note: This question is not about `WebMathematica`. I speculate it is capable of doing everything about to be discussed.*

With its diverse capabilities and near endless applications, it seems that Mathematica is the `Swiss Knife` of high-level programming languages. So it got me thinking if it would be possible to build a small blog-like website (home, articles, apps, about me, etc.) with minimal coding from HTML, CSS, JavaScript, etc. Has this ever been done? If so, **are there any live examples and tutorials for this?**

Is it also possible to code a minimal web server without using a backend (PHP, Node, etc.) or a web server (Apache, MS NET, Oracle, etc.); perhaps one that can be coded only to drive the small website? I imagine `Dataset` could be substituted for SQL so that shouldn't be a problem. Any thoughts?

Comment: I am not a lawyer, but I do not think the normal license allows one to do this. i.e. if you have Mathematica on a server, accepting commands from anyone, then you are basically making your Mathematica copy available to be used by anyone other than you. I think the license allows only the person who bought Mathemtica to use it.  But anyway, I think this duplicate/related to of [can-mathematica-act-like-a-web-server](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/123805/can-mathematica-act-like-a-web-server)  and ...

Comment: ... [implementing-a-100-mathematica-http-server](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/27785/implementing-a-100-mathematica-http-server) and [question-about-using-mathematica-on-a-linux-server](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/275412/question-about-using-mathematica-on-a-linux-server)

Comment: ... and [making-a-website-with-mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/152663/making-a-website-with-mathematica)  btw, there is a difference between using Mathematica to generate a webpage, and actually running Mathematica itself on the server. In the first case it is OK to do, I was talking above about running your copy of Mathematica on the server. I do not think this is allowed. (but someone who knows more about this can correct me)

Comment: Many of related topics can be found by a simple search for obvious keywords. Have you tried and read those topics? I agree information is a scattered a little but is there something specific that you couldn't find an answer for?

Comment: @Kuba no, it was just a general question. What I am really interested in is if there is a complete tutorial for building a small blog with vanilla Mathematica along with some live links to some examples.

Comment: @Nassar thank you ill have a look.

Comment: I have no clue what vanilla means in this context

Comment: @JasonB. The term vanilla has its origin in the practice of web development of not using any libraries or frameworks with your JavaScript, or CSS, or PHP, etc. In other words, this question is restricted to only using Mathematica--no WebMathematica or other Wolfram products.

Answer (score 8):

There is an exact solution you are looking for

- Pure Wolfram Engine (freeware!) [Webserver](https://github.com/KirillBelovTest/HTTPHandler) with many features supported like WebSockets, GET/POST (but no TLS support so far).
- [Template engine](https://jerryi.github.io/wljs-docs/wlx) that let you write in Wolfram Language XML (a superset of XML and WL) web-applications with data-binding, dynamics and real-time calculations.

[image]

It is free and runs locally on your PC/Mac.